Application of Stolz-Cesaro Theorem to a Series
I was given as an exercise to show that if $0 < s < 1$ and $\beta \geq 0$ then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-s)n^\beta\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s^{n-k}}{k^\beta} = 1.$$ Clearly $\beta = 0$ is a trivial case but I was hinted to use the Stolz-Cesàro theorem to show the $\beta>0$ case. However, I do not see how to factor the given sequence into sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ that satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem.
I believe the exercise was supposed to be used in a later proof to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s^{n-k}}{k^\beta} = 0$

Let's consider your limit without the $(1-s)$ factor
\begin{align} 
 \lim_{n\to \infty} n^\beta\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s^{n-k}}{k^\beta} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-\beta}s^{-k}}{ n^{-\beta} s^{-n}}.
\end{align}
Consider the sequences,
\begin{align}
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-\beta}s^{-k} , \quad b_n = n^{-\beta} s^{-n}.
\end{align}
Apply the theorem,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}  = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^{-\beta}s^{-n-1}}{(n+1)^{-\beta}s^{-n-1} -n^{-\beta} s^{-n} } = \frac{1}{1-s}
\end{align}

Beat me to it, thanks for the help!

Okay, I figured out the solution – it was more simple than I thought.
Write
$$(1-s)n^\beta\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s^{n-k}}{k^\beta} = \left(\frac{1}{(1-s)n^\beta s^n}\right)^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s^{-k}}{k^\beta}$$
and let $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{s^{-k}}{k^\beta}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{(1-s)n^\beta s^n}$. For all but finitely many $n$, $b_n$ is monotonically increasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = \infty$, since $0<s<1$.
Then,
$$a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{s^{-n-1}}{(n+1)^\beta}$$
and
\begin{align*}
b_{n+1}-b_n = \frac{1}{(1-s)(n+1)^\beta s^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{(1-s)n^\beta s^n} &= \frac{1}{(1-s)s^n}\left(\frac{1}{s(n+1)^\beta} - \frac{1}{n^\beta}\right)\\
&=\frac{n^\beta-s(n+1)^\beta}{s^{n+1}(1-s)n^\beta(n+1)^\beta}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} = \frac{\frac{s^{-n-1}}{(n+1)^\beta}}{\frac{n^\beta-s(n+1)^\beta}{s^{n+1}(1-s)n^\beta(n+1)^\beta}} = \frac{(1-s)n^\beta}{n^\beta-s(n+1)^\beta} \to 1.
\end{align*}
